# How to trigger a different jobs in a master job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a job which contains a field of type string parameter (called JOB_NAME), in this string parameter, I will just fill it with another job name.
in the same job, I created "trigger/call builds on another project", in the latest, I will just provide the $JOB_NAME but it is not working.

My second question is how to fill $JOB_NAME field with some existing job using regular expresion or something else.

Can someone provide me clear steps, I am not that expert in Jenkins.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Groovy Postbuild Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Groovy+Postbuild+Plugin) to achieve this.

Once you install the plugin, go to **Post-build Actions** and choose **Groovy Postbuild** option and add the following script to it.

Then, whenever you run your job it will ask for `JOB_NAME` as you have defined it as a parameter in your job and whatever project name you will enter, it will trigger that job in the downstream.

```
import hudson.model.*
import jenkins.model.*

def build = Thread.currentThread().executable

def jobPattern = manager.build.buildVariables.get("JOB_NAME") 
def matchedJobs = Jenkins.instance.items.findAll { job ->
    job.name =~ /$jobPattern/
}
matchedJobs.each { job ->
    println "Triggering ${job.name} in the down stream...."
    job.scheduleBuild(1, new Cause.UpstreamCause(build), new ParametersAction([ new StringParameterValue("PROPERTY1", "PROPERTY1VALUE"),new StringParameterValue("PROPERTY2", "PROPERTY2VALUE")]))
}
```

Comment: what about if the called job use predefined parameters?

Comment: @Foudel you can pass them downstream by using `ParametersAction([ new StringParameterValue("PROPERTY1", "PROPERTY1VALUE"),new StringParameterValue("PROPERTY2", "PROPERTY2VALUE")]))`